# PhpUnit "press" method in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I am working in a Laravel 5.3 project where I am testing the project using PhpUnit 5.7.27. Sorry for the picture because I want to show you guys the real code for better understanding.[image: this is the code of the button]

I have added name for the button you can see [name = 'add_client'] in the selected line. I have tried adding Id but PhpUnit showing me

> InvalidArgumentException : Could not find a form that has submit button [add_client]

I am trying to press the button using `$this->press('add_client')`.
Any solution would be greatly helpful to me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, PHP Unit tells you, that there is no form on your page. Moreover, what are you going to test? As I can see your `add_client` button used to open the modal, and the `press` method is prepared for forms.

Comment: Great to hear from you sir, actually I am trying to add a client and check the entry in database using "seeInDatabase" method. After clicking the add_client button, the modal opens and Then I have to input the name and other informations of the client. How can I do that sir?

Comment: So, does your modal contains form? If so, just follow the [docs - Interacting With Forms](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/application-testing). Use `visit`, `type` and `press` method for testing your form. Also, check that your button has `add_client` name attribute.